# How to make a mysql query when a single table have the same value for two different attributes?

Tags: mysql

I have made two tables :

```
Member(member_id,name,contact) 
Registration(loan_id,member_id,witness1_id,witness2_id,status)
primary key of Member,registration table are member_id and loan_id respectively.
```

The witness1_id and witness2_ id are the member_id in member table which means each member have two witnesses who are themselves the member of the organization.
I want to make a query which gives the list of members along with the witnesses details whose status is 1, output should be in the following schema :

```
   (member_id,name_of_member,witness1_name,witness1_contact,witness2_name,
 witness2_contact)
```

To make the problem easy to understand, I have not included the full schema rather I have used the required fields.

```
example :
Member
member_id     name      contact
1             xyz       1111111111
2             abc       2222222222
3             pqr       3333333333
4             efg       4444444444

Registration
loan_id       member_id   witness2_id    witness2_id   status
123           1           2              3             1
124           2           1              3             0
125           4           2              1             1

output/result
member_id     name      witness1_name  witness1_contact  witness2_name    witness2_contact
1             xyz       abc            22222222          pqr              333333333
4             efg       abc            22222222          xyz              111111111
```

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what you want. Can you show some sample data and the expected results?

Comment: post your schema and few dummy data on sqlfiddle please...

Answer (score 0):

You need to prefix the columns with the name of the tables, or the aliases used in the query.

```
SELECT member.name, registration.status
FROM member
JOIN registration ON ( registration.member_id = member.member_id )
WHERE ...
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
SELECT r.member_id, m.name as name_of_member
, w1.name as witness1_name, w1.contact as witness1_contact
, w2.name as witness2_name, w2.contact as witness2_contact
 FROM registration as r
 LEFT JOIN member as m ON (r.member_id = m.member_id)
 LEFT JOIN member as w1 ON (r.witness1_id = w1.member_id)
 LEFT JOIN member as w2 ON (r.witness2_id = w2.member_id)
 WHERE r.status = 1
```